# Java AWT Canvas - Multiple colors in one window

Tags: java, awt, java-canvas

I was trying to make rectangles that have multiple colors with Java AWT, but whenever I use the `setForeground(color)` method, it changes the color of all objects in the window. Is there a way to change the color without that happening?

The code that I wrote looked like this:

```
setBackground(Color.WHITE);
setForeground(Color.BLACK);
g.fillRect(20,20,10,30);
setForeground(Color.BLUE);
g.fillRect(40,40,20,30);
```

The variable g was the Graphics object and I was writing a method in a class that extended the Canvas class.

I've looked for the solution for a long time, but I didn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the Color of the Graphics object:

```
//setForeground(Color.BLACK);
g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
g.fillRect(20,20,10,30);
//setForeground(Color.BLUE);
g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
g.fillRect(40,40,20,30);
```

Also, you really should be using Swing (not AWT) which is more advanced than AWT. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.